# Python: Summing values nested inside different dictionaries in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary called "high_low_teams_in_profile" which looks like this:

```
{   
    m_profile1:
        {
            team_size1:
                {   
                    low: 1,

                    high: 1

                },
            team_size2:
                {   
                    low: 1,

                    high: 1

                }
        },
    m_profile2:
        {
            team_size1:
                {   
                    low: 1,

                    high: 1

                },
            team_size2:
                {   
                    low: 1,

                    high: 1

                }

        }   
}
```

And I want to get {m_profile1: 4, m_profile2: 4}

What is the most eloquent way to do it in python?
Right now I have the following:

```
new_num_teams_in_profile = {}
for profile in high_low_teams_in_profile:
    new_num_teams_in_profile[profile]= dict((team_size, sum(high_low_teams_in_profile[profile][team_size].values())) for team_size in high_low_teams_in_profile[profile])

new_num_teams_in_profile= dict((profile, sum(new_num_teams_in_profile[profile].values())) for profile in new_num_teams_in_profile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'd say it's the most Pythonic, but it's the most [*functional*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/functional-programming/info):

```
p = high_low_teams_in_profile
{ prof:sum(p[prof][team][hl]
           for team in p[prof]
           for hl in p[prof][team])
  for prof in p}
```

The arguments of `sum` is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) and the outer `{ prof:sum(...) for prof in p}` is a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Oh nice! I like this one =) neat and concise!

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be the most pythonic, the following code should work and is more readable than your original version. Note the `iteritems()` method, which allows access to both the keys and values of the dict, while `itervalues()`, as the name suggests, only iterates the values of the dict.

```
final = {}
for key, sizes in high_low_teams_in_profile.iteritems():
    total = 0
    for value in sizes.itervalues():
        s = sum(value.itervalues())
        total += s

    final[key] = total

print final
```

In addition, you could use the following. While it is a shorter number of lines, it is slightly more difficult to read.

```
final = {}
for key, sizes in high_low_teams_in_profile.iteritems():
    total = sum([sum(value.itervalues()) for value in sizes.itervalues()])
    final[key] = total

print final
```